# IE9, xml, zone security, xmlhttp

Tags: security, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, httprequest

MSDN has an article that describes native xmlhttp.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx#_id
```

As the article describes, I have enabled native xml http. But this xml demo still doesn't run in ie9 on my local iis 7 server. It runs on the original site. If I download it to the local web server, it doesn't. The xmlhttp request

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); doesn't return an object.
```

The demo is from the w3schools site http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_first.

This is the HTML.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCD(i)
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(11)">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the xml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <!--  Edited by XMLSpy® 
  --> 
- <CATALOG>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Eros</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>One night only</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1998</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.10</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1973</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.50</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1999</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1971</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Stop</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
  </CATALOG>
```

Where do the security issues happen that cause this demo to not run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE, XML, zone security, XMLhttprequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033284/ie-xml-zone-security-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: The problem was a non-standard xml file format.  Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033284/ie-xml-zone-security-xmlhttprequest