# IE, XML, zone security, XMLhttprequest

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

MSDN has an article that describes native xmlhttp.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx#_id

As the article describes, I have enabled native xml http.  But this xml demo still doesn't run on my local server. It runs on the original site.  If I download it to the local web server, it doesn't.  The xmlhttp request

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

doesn't return an object.

The demo is from the w3schools site http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_first.

This is the HTML.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
//i=0;

function displayCD(i)
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(11)">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <!--  Edited by XMLSpy® 
  --> 
- <CATALOG>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Eros</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>One night only</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1998</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.10</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1973</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.50</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1999</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1971</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Stop</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
- <CD>
  <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
  </CATALOG>
```

Where do the security issues happen that cause this demo to not run?

Comment: Step #1, declare your variables. e.g. var xmlhttp = new window.XmlHttpRequest();

Comment: Issue #2: What's the URL of this webpage? If it's file://, it's not going to work with the native object in IE because IE only allows you to use HTTP/HTTPS with the window.XmlHttpRequest object.

Comment: Step #3: Don't ever pass false for the Async parameter. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/do-not-use-xmlhttprequest-in-synchronous-mode-unless-you-like-to-hang.aspx

Comment: The url is http://ultra/xml/debug.html.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT If I declare the variable as you suggested, I get this error. "Object expected".  These are the error details. 'Webpage error details User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0) Timestamp: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 23:35:37 UTC Message: Object expected Line: 17 Char: 3 Code: 0 URI: http://ultra/xml/xml_getdata.html Message: 'x' is undefined Line: 35 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: http://ultra/xml/xml_getdata.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the formatting in the xml file that I was trying to open with the xmlhttprequest.  When I removed the - in the file, it worked.  Here is the HTML that worked along with the XML.

HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCD(i)
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD(5)">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<CATALOG>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1982</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Eros</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>One night only</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1998</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.10</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1973</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.50</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>10.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1999</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.70</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1995</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1997</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1971</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1996</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1990</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Stop</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1988</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1983</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>9.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.90</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1985</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Red</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>London</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>7.80</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
<CD>
  <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE> 
  <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST> 
  <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY> 
  <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY> 
  <PRICE>8.20</PRICE> 
  <YEAR>1987</YEAR> 
  </CD>
  </CATALOG>
```

Thanks for your help.